# PHP Toolkit 20.0 (Enterprise) Upsert/Update Custom Object - deserializer not found

Tags: custom-object, soap, upsert, deserialize, php-toolkit

I'm using PHP Toolkit 20.0 (Enterprise) and the latest WSDL.  Partner also fails for me.

I can successfully create (using PHP Toolkit create) objects of this type.
All my attempts to Update or Upsert these fields are failing.

I'm a reasonably experienced developer....but a reasonably inexperienced SOAP/SFDC developer.

My current failure:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXException: 
  Deserializing parameter 'sObjects':  
    could not find deserializer for type {urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com}Serial_Number__c
```

I'm baffled.  Any help on what I'm missing is very welcomed.  Thanks!

Here's the tl;dr version:

I created a custom object called 'Serial_Number__c' that contains custom fields:

```
Name                   /* a serial number text string */
Account__c             /* a Master-Detail AccountId
                          to associate the serial number
                          with a standard Account */
Serial_ID__c           /* the ID for serial number record.
                          Format:  S-{YYYY}-{0000000000} auto increment */
Warranty_Expire__c     /* a Date (apparently in text string format)
                          Default empty     */
Warranty_Extended__c   /* a Checkbox (apparently boolean one or zero)
                          Default Unchecked */
```

Here is the code (tl;dr version):

```
$sObject = new stdClass();
$sObject->Account__c         = '00146000003Sb9GAAS'; // Account__c is a SFDC Account.Id
$sObject->Name               = '54545454545';
$sObject->Serial_ID__c       = 'S-2017-0000000002';
$sObject->Warranty_Expire__c = '2017-03-09';

$upsertResponse = $soap_client->upsert('Serial_ID__c', array($sObject), 'Serial_Number__c');
```

array sent to upsert:

```
Array
(
  [0] => stdClass Object
    (
      [Account__c] => 00146000003Sb9GAAS
      [Name] => 54545454545
      [Serial_ID__c] => S-2017-0000000002
      [Warranty_Expire__c] => 2017-03-09
    )
 )
```

SOAP REQUEST:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope 
  xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
  xmlns:ns1="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <ns1:SessionHeader>
      <ns1:sessionId>...removed just because.  No problem with connectivity...</ns1:sessionId>
    </ns1:SessionHeader>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:upsert>
      <ns1:externalIDFieldName>Serial_ID__c</ns1:externalIDFieldName>
      <ns1:sObjects xsi:type="ns1:Serial_Number__c">
      <Account__c>00146000003Sb9GAAS</Account__c>
      <Name>54545454545</Name>
      <Serial_ID__c>S-2017-0000000002</Serial_ID__c>
      <Warranty_Expire__c>2017-03-09</Warranty_Expire__c></ns1:sObjects>
    </ns1:upsert>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

RESPONSE:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXException: 
  Deserializing parameter 'sObjects':  
    could not find deserializer for type {urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com}Serial_Number__c
```

Added information:

I don't understand SOAP Namespaces very well.

Here is the section of XML that describes my custom object:

```
<complexType name="Serial_Number__c">
    <complexContent>
        <extension base="ens:sObject">
            <sequence>
            <element name="Account__c" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:ID"/>
            <element name="Account__r" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="ens:Account"/>
            <element name="ActivityHistories" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult"/>
            <element name="AttachedContentDocuments" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult"/>
            <element name="Attachments" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult"/>
            <element name="CombinedAttachments" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult"/>
            <element name="ContentDocumentLinks" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult"/>
            <element name="CreatedBy" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="ens:User"/>
            <element name="CreatedById" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:ID"/>
            <element name="CreatedDate" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
            <element name="DuplicateRecordItems" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult"/>
            <element name="Emails" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult"/>
            <element name="Events" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult"/>
            <element name="FeedSubscriptionsForEntity" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult"/>
            <element name="Feeds" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult"/>
            <element name="Histories" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult"/>
            <element name="IsDeleted" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:boolean"/>
            <element name="LastActivityDate" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:date"/>
            <element name="LastModifiedBy" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="ens:User"/>
            <element name="LastModifiedById" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:ID"/>
            <element name="LastModifiedDate" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
            <element name="LastReferencedDate" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
            <element name="LastViewedDate" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
            <element name="LookedUpFromActivities" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult"/>
            <element name="Name" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
            <element name="Notes" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult"/>
            <element name="NotesAndAttachments" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult"/>
            <element name="OpenActivities" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult"/>
            <element name="ProcessInstances" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult"/>
            <element name="ProcessSteps" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult"/>
            <element name="RecordAssociatedGroups" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult"/>
            <element name="Serial_ID__c" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
            <element name="SystemModstamp" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
            <element name="Tasks" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult"/>
            <element name="TopicAssignments" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult"/>
            <element name="UserRecordAccess" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="ens:UserRecordAccess"/>
            <element name="Warranty_Expire__c" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:date"/>
            <element name="Warranty_Extended__c" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:boolean"/>
            </sequence>
        </extension>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

Comment: Checking if you had tried upsert for standard object like mentioned [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit_20.0_Upsert_Sample_(Enterprise))

Comment: I just ran the mentioned test.

Create works fine.  Upsert fails the same way.

Comment: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Deserializing parameter 'sObjects':  could not find deserializer for type {urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com}Contact

Comment: Did you try using different wsdl version. Error is quite strange.

Comment: It looks like there is something wrong in my setup.  I'm not sure what.

In addition, |'m wondering if the Master-Detail thing is what's failing.  Am I missing something with Account__r?

My gut says yes, but I can't find examples that make it clear so far.

Comment: When I switch the sample example to Partner wsdl I receive the following error:

PHP Fatal error:  SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'type' property in /home/byronco/public_html/adept/Force.com-Toolkit-for-PHP/soapclient/SforceBaseClient.php on line 499

 SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'type' property
Modify the code like this:

 $sObject->FirstName = 'George';
...
 $sObject->Email = 'test@test.com';
 $sObject->type = 'Contact';

org.xml.sax.SAXException: SimpleDeserializer encountered a child element, which is NOT expected, in something it was trying to deserialize.

Comment: It's almost like my wsdl is not properly loading (just a thought) ???

How do I verify that?

Comment: With the Enterprise WSDL you need to download it again every time you add a new custom object or make a change to the custom fields. The Enterprise WSDL contains a snapshot of the orgs Schema at the time it was generated.  Try getting a fresh copy of the Enterprise WSDL and checking it contains a complexType for `Serial_Number__c`

Comment: I have the current WSDL.  

Are there other things outside the Toolkit that I need to do to use the WSDL ??

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a namespace issue in the XML message.

```
<ns1:upsert>
  <ns1:externalIDFieldName>Serial_ID__c</ns1:externalIDFieldName>
  <ns1:sObjects xsi:type="ns1:Serial_Number__c">
    <Account__c>00146000003Sb9GAAS</Account__c>
    <Name>54545454545</Name>
    <Serial_ID__c>S-2017-0000000002</Serial_ID__c>
    <Warranty_Expire__c>2017-03-09</Warranty_Expire__c>
  </ns1:sObjects>
</ns1:upsert>
```

Note the `xsi:type="ns1:Serial_Number__c"`. That is saying the Serial_Number__c type is defined in the same namespace as sObjects, upsert, etc.

- xmlns:ns1="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com"

That doesn't sound right. Usually the sObjects themselves are split off from the types that drive the API. You would typically see something like:

- xmlns:urn1="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com"

And then expect that namespace to be used for Serial_Number__c. E.g.

```
<ns1:upsert>
  <ns1:externalIDFieldName>Serial_ID__c</ns1:externalIDFieldName>
  <ns1:sObjects xsi:type="urn1:Serial_Number__c">
    <Account__c>00146000003Sb9GAAS</Account__c>
    <Name>54545454545</Name>
    <Serial_ID__c>S-2017-0000000002</Serial_ID__c>
    <Warranty_Expire__c>2017-03-09</Warranty_Expire__c>
  </ns1:sObjects>
</ns1:upsert>
```

I've never really tried to use PHP so I'm not sure how that translates into the toolkit usage. Worst case, create an [issue](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-PHP/issues) in the Force.com-Toolkit-for-PHP github project.

Answer (score 0):

Nope.  Too early morning.  It works okay for update, but not for upsert.

While this is still a helpful update....it's not the solution.

I discovered this morning something I didn't know...that of course makes perfect sense.

When I read through the Custom Object documentation I either overlooked the fact (which seems really obvious in retrospect) that a custom object has it's own ID field.  I thought I had to create my own ID (Serial_ID__c).

After playing around more with the Partner version of the API I observed errors that said I didn't have an ID in my objects...so this morning I did a describeSObject and discovered the ID field that I didn't realize was in there.

After adding the *real* ID to the object, I no longer see the error I was seeing.

There are other things I need to resolve, but this particular issue appears to be resolved.

Comment: As a workaround, I split up my calls to use create & update and skip upsert for now.

Comment: I think I've messed up the external ID field. 

I'm betting that is why it's failing for upsert.